# How to write a "wrapper" for my case

Tags: c#

I have a program written in C and running in unix. But due to certain platform change, now I have to run it in C# to integrate it into an system talking with SQL database.

So how can I do this? Is it possible to write a wrapper to let it run in windows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you compile your code on windows? There are c compilers for windows, you know. And why do you need to run it in C#? Can you explain?

Comment: How does cygwin relate to this?

Comment: You can access (most) SQL databases from C#; search the database provider's website for C# (or .net) API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but you might want to look into [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/).